# heroku reference file path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

How do you reference a file when a ruby on rails application is deployed on Heroku?  I'm using CURL::EASY and the cert parameter requires a path to the .p12 cert.  This works on my local, but not when I deploy to heroku.

Answer (score 3):

try bash with your heroku

```
heroku run bash -a your-app-name
```

It will connect you the file directory. Type `ls` to view all files of your application.

Try `more Gemfile.lock` to view the code on your file.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
Rails.root.join('/path/to/cert')
```

**However**, committing a private certificate file to a code repository is very poor practice, for numerous security reasons. A much preferrable solution would be to store the certificate in a heroku config file using:

```
heroku config:set CERTIFICATE="your cert source here"
```

And then pass it to Curl::Easy using:

```
my_curl_easy.cacert = ENV['CERTIFICATE']
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried heroku config:set CERTIFICATE="your cert source here" however it still doesn't work.  I did heroku config:set CERTIFICATE="/path/to/cert"  Is that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Do you know how to view the stacktrace for curl in ruby?  Maybe the error message I'm getting is something different than it can't find the file.  The error message I get is A Curl::Err::SSLCertificateError Problem with the local SSL certificate